# How to understand such a random variable from the perspective of probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I just came across such a situation:

Consider such a space that glues 3 $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ together at 0, we call it $S$. That means the image of the random variable from the sample space $\Omega$ to $S$ is always non-negative, but the only difference is which $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ it is on. Thus, label them with indices 1,2,and 3. Let probability space be $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$. If we assume there is a random variable $Q: \Omega \rightarrow S$. How can we understand such random variable from the perspective of random variable's definition in probability theory?

I have the feeling that in this case $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}$, but I really suck in probability theory and do not know whether it is true.

Another problem is the map $Q$ looks like a composite function. For example, if we simulate sampling on $S$, it seems that we need to give a probability that the observation of the random variable is on which specific $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and then decide $Q(\omega)\in B$, $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Does it mean in this step, for each $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, the random variable on it can have different distribution under the conditon that the random variable's image is on that.

Sorry for my bad wording. Anyway, I just have a problem in understanding this as a random variable.

Comment: This is just a particular sample space $S$, it  could be equivalently mapped via 1-1 correspondence to $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, 0) \cup [0,1) \cup [1,\infty)$. Or ou could represent all objects in $S$ via $(k,x) \in \{0,1,2\} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thx, Michael. I agree with you that it could be presented in the latter way you proposed. I am still writing it down in detail how to explain it logically.